# Zooming and Panning of two images at a time in a single view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I wanted to zoom and pan of two images in a single view at a time. When user tries to pinch one image it should reflect to other image as how first image behaves and if user pan the one image it should reflect the other image as how first image behaves. Both the images should not overlapped.

I have tried single image using UIScrollView it works perfectly but when it comes to two images I don't know how to call UIScrollView Delegate method purposely viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? for two scrollviews.

[image]

Comment: put each image in its own scrollview and set the content offset and zoom scale of one scroll view to other by detecting changes using UIScrollView Delegates.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr viewForZooming in this delegate method which image view should return?

Comment: create outlets for both scrollviews and in `viewForZooming` delegate method check the `scrollView` and depends on whether it is scrollviewA return imageA or if it is scrollviewB return imageB. And then use `scrollViewDidZoom` delegate and set the zoom scale of scrollview to other one.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr It is working perfectly when it is zooming. But when I’m trying to pan/drag the image view I’m setting content offset to each scrollview in scrollViewWillEndDragging delegate method. Problem is the other scrollview is effecting at the last because it is end dragging is there anyway to two image views drags simultenously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create outlets for both scrollviews, say `scrollviewA` and `scrollviewB`. In `viewForZooming` delegate method check the scrollView and depends on whether it is `scrollviewA` return `imageA` or if it is `scrollviewB` return `imageB`.

Then use `scrollViewDidZoom` delegate and set the zoom scale of scrollview to other one by using the same checking above mentioned.

For drag, try using `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method and set the content offset of one scroll view to other.